# Replacement for Hill's r/d food for cats

Tags: cats, eating

We have been feeding our 8-years old cat with Hill's Prescription Diet r/d (both dry food and wet canned food). Unfortunately, the canned version is no longer available in shops in my country so I thought about replacing it with something similar.

1. Can we use Hill's Prescription Diet w/d or m/d? Would it make a difference?
2. Can I combine wet w/d or wet m/d with dry r/d? I still have some supplies.

Some more info about our cat. This is an indoor male, sterilized, mixed breed, around 5.5 kg. I used to feed him really badly and he ended up with megacolon problems. Fortunately, no surgery was necessary, the enema helped. After that, I've got a recommendation from a local dietician to use Hill's w/d and that really helped. She's no longer working, so I am looking for advice.

**Edit:**

Answers to Allison C questions:

1. We haven't switched from w/d to r/d. For the last 3 years we have been using r/d only.
2. r/d was recommended to fight cat's overweight, which was a possible reason of megacolon. It didn't help the cat to lose weight, but megacolon problems have never come back since starting it. My guess is that this could be because:

   - I started to use also wet food (before I used only dry food),
   - r/d contains fiber helping to digest better,
   - we change drinking water more often,
   - we play with the cat more often,
   - and last but not least, it sometimes eats grass in our balcony, which helps him vomit hairballs.
3. I haven't consulted my vet recently about my cat's diet. The only feedback I had was that might cat was overweighted. Plus recently we have made blood tests before teeth descaling and results were fine.

Comment: A few questions: Why did you switch from w/d to r/d? What are you currently addressing with r/d? What is your current veterinarian's advice or assessment of your cat's health?

Comment: @AllisonC Thanks for your questions. I updated my post with the answers. Now when I wrote all that I wonder if applying r/d (so something to reduce weight) as a regular food is something really necessary for my cat. If there is no easy way to lose weight perhaps feeding with food that contains fiber and is not based only on dry food is enough...